# How to make navbar disappear when I click on link tag from menu

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I have this navbar it works how I want it too but my main problem is I want the dropdown menu to disappear by clicking any links on the menu because I am not sure what to add to my current code to get it to behave as desired. Thanks any help would be appreciated

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
         <a href="#zero"><img src="log.png"></a>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#lowerSec" class="active">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#container">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my JS

It works fine I just one the additional feature that I mentioned on the title since I don't know how to do it

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).on('scroll', function()
   {

    if($(window).scrollTop())
   {
     $('nav').addClass('black');
    }

   else
   {
     $('nav').removeClass('black');
   }
   }
   )

   $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".menu").on("click", function() {
   $("nav ul").toggleClass("active");
   });
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `nav ul li a` to your click function.  Since I don't know what your markup looks like here is a quick demo:

```js
$(".menu, nav ul li a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("nav ul").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
ul{
  display:none;
}

ul.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<nav>
  <button class="menu">
  Menu
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

With jquery you can comma separate selectors.  Since you already have the functionality to toggle the active class just add the `nav ul li a` to your existing function.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS styling may be a potential solution.
all tags are displayed as blocks so in your CSS file add

```
    .makeDisappear{
    display:none
    }
```

Although, I do recommend renaming your id for your navbar something a bit more unique.

so example jQuery would be:

```
$("a").on("click",function(){
document.getElementById("navbar").classList.add("makeDisappear");

//or simply $("#navbar").addClass("makeDisappear")
})
```

to make your nav bar reappear
change display:none to display:block

Comment: I tried it but it does not do anything for the makeDisappear class what tag do I give to?